# How to detect is an element in an array is one character long and matches the first character of any element in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, function, ecmascript-6

So I have a situation where I have an array of names for which I need to detect whether any of those names consists of simply an initial.

For example: Jon, Paul, G, Smith, B, Morgan

I need to detect which of those elements are initials (one character long) and then compare them against another array of names.

For example: Morgan, Paul, George, Jon, Smith

If any one of those initials matches the first letter of any of the names in the second array, I need to return a value of true.

```
var myStringArray = ["Jon", "Paul", "G", "Smith", "B", "Morgan"];
var myStringArray2 = ["Morgan", "Paul", "George", "Jon", "Smith"];
var arrayLength = myStringArray.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    if (myStringArray[i].length == 1) {
    //Compare myStringArray[i] to every value of myStringArray2
    }
}
```

I'm unsure of how to go about this. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the length of each of the names and whether they're equal to 0 and use [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) check if any of the names in the second array match:

```js
var myStringArray = ["Jon", "Paul", "G", "Smith", "B", "Morgan"];
var myStringArray2 = ["Morgan", "Paul", "George", "Jon", "Smith"];

function findName(arr1, arr2) {
 for (let initial of arr1) {
  if (initial.length === 1) {
   return arr2.findIndex(name => name[0] === initial) != -1
  }
 }
}

console.log(findName(myStringArray, myStringArray2))
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple - use `some` with `filter` and `startsWith` like so:

```js
const namesAndInitials = ["Jon", "Paul", "G", "Smith", "B", "Morgan"];
const names = ["Morgan", "Paul", "George", "Jon", "Smith"];

const initials = namesAndInitials.filter(e => e.length == 1);

const firstLetter = initials.some(initial => names.find(name => name.startsWith(initial)));

console.log(firstLetter); //Should return true because G for George
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just **loop** through each array and compare as shown below.

```js
var arrWithInitials = ["Jon", "Paul", "G", "Smith", "B", "Morgan"];
var arrWithoutInitials = ["Morgan", "Paul", "George", "Jon", "Smith"];
var arr = [];

arrWithInitials.forEach(e => {
  if (e.length == 1) {
    arr.push(e);
  }
});

arr.forEach(e => {
  arrWithoutInitials.forEach(element => {
    if (e == element[0]) {
      console.log(true);
    }
  });
});
```